# What does 'vector <double> hour {vector<double>(24, -1)};' mean?

Tags: c++, vector

Is this a vector of 24 vectors all initialised to '-1'? If so, then why isn't the hour vector of type 'vector' instead of 'double'?

I can't visualise the data structure this'll form.

Comment: It could've just been written as `vector<double> hour(24, -1);`, the rest is just superfluous, no different to writing `std::string s = std::string("hello");` as opposed to `std::string s = "hello";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), this is the constructor form

```
vector(size_type count,
       const T& value,
       const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
// Constructs the container with <count> copies of elements, each with value <value>.
```

with the default allocator.

Hence it constructs a vector of size `24` with each element of that vector set to `-1`.

And the type of `hour` is neither `double` *nor* `vector`, it's `vector<double>` which is, surprisingly, a vector of doubles :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<double> hour { vector<double>(24, -1) };
```

This will result in a single vector of 24 -1s named `hour`. The `vector<double>(24, -1)` inside of the `{}` is a temporary vector that is created in order to create the `hour` vector.

Visually, with '.0' omitted:

```
{-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}
```

> If so, then why isn't the hour vector of type 'vector' instead of 'double'?

The hour vector is of type `vector<double>` The <> are for templates and determine at compile time what type the vector will contain.

If it had said `vector<int> hour` instead, this would have been a vector of `int` values instead of `double` values.

Answer (score 0):

it is first constructing a instance of a vector of double with 24 items initialized with -1.0(implicitly), then it is copy constructed to create a new vector of double named hour.

update : 
modern compiler will have optimizations that uses move semantics for this operation, and will not do a deep copying.

the better way for doing this is simply `vector<double> hour(24, -1);`

Comment: *Modern compiler* – Move semantics are there since C++11. There is practically no chance a somewhat recent compiler copying the temporary.

Comment: @Swordfish: Not only that, `{}` for initializing non-aggregates is also a C++11 feature. So if the code compiled at all, it will move instead of copy.

Answer (score 0):

`vector<double>(24, -1)` creates a vector with with size `24` and each value initialized to `-1`. `vector <double> hour{vector<double>(24, -1)}` uses a copy constructor to make a copy of this vector so it ends up with `24` `-1`s as well.

```
{-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0}
```

Comment: Since C++11 the temporary will get moved.